# Async IDataErrorInfo - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, .net-4.0

I have a problem when I want to use IDataErrorInfo (.NET 4.0) asynchronously. This code works perfectly.

```
EditViewModel.cs

public class EditViewModel : CustomViewModel, IDataErrorInfo
{
    string IDataErrorInfo.Error
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    string IDataErrorInfo.this[string propertyName] => _validationHandler.Validate(this, propertyName);

}

ValidationHandler.cs

public string Validate(object currentInstance, string propertyName)
{
    // BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA

    return ReturnErrorString

}
```

What I want now is to be able to do it asynchronously. The code I leave below does not work. It does not return error or anything, only my form does not open and my application freezes.

```
private async Task<string> AsyncValidation(object currentInstance, string propertyName)
{
    return await TaskEx.Run(() =>
        {
            // BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA

            return ReturnErrorString
        }
    );
}

public string Validate(object currentInstance, string propertyName)
{
    return AsyncValidation(currentInstance, propertyName).Result;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: You are deadlocking the UI thread, by blocking on the `Result` property getter, in the same thread that your `await` statement needs in order to complete. Your question lacks a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, so it's impossible to provide a good answer (though you may get poor attempts at an answer anyway). It does not appear that there's a) any good reason to make this `async` (if you're blocking, then it's not really async), and b) any good reason to `await` (you could have just returned the `Task` that the `Run()` method returns).

Comment: You should not use IDataErrorInfo for async validation, because it's hard to make (proper) async validation with this interface. At least use INotifyDataErrorInfo instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't actually implement the `IDataErrorInfo` interface asynchronously as it just defines a property and an indexer, none of which are or may be  implemented asynchronously.

Calling an `async` method in the indexer will *not* make the validation asynchronous as the indexer itself is not being awaited by the validation framework. There is nothing you can do to change this really. An `async` method should be `async` all the way and you should not mix blocking and async code: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx.

You may want to look into the `INotifyDataErrorInfo` interface that was introduced in the .NET Framework 4.5. This interface does support asynchronous validation. Please refer to the following TechNet article for more information and an example: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19490.wpf-4-5-validating-data-in-using-the-inotifydataerrorinfo-interface.aspx.

Answer (score -1):

Your new `Validate` function should look like this :

```
public async string Validate(object currentInstance, string propertyName)
{
    result = await AsyncValidation(currentInstance, propertyName);
    return result;
}
```